# Measure transmission power of USRP

Tags: power, antenna, transmission, sdr

I am working with USRP(Universal Software Radio Peripheral) having power gain (mentioned in specifications) of 17dBm to 20dBm. I am using 3dbi omni-directional VERT900 antenna with it. I know the operating frequency 'f'. How could I find the actual output power of this setup?

Actually I want to connect the setup with power amplifier but firstly I need to find power output without amplifier. I don't know exactly how this will happen?

Comment: USRP? Output power will be between 17 to 20 dBm.

Comment: it's an SDR. Mine is from National Instrument NI 2922. Attached in the link is its specification list: http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/375868c.pdf . My question is how can I actually compute its power in running state. Like do I have to put values in some formula or is there any application installed at receiving end which can give me actual gain during transmission.

Comment: @winny How can I actually verify the readings after connecting power amplifier?

Comment: You are sprikling information into the comments and changing the question from what is the output power to what will happen at the receiving end? Please edit the question and add relevent information. SDR=software defined radio.

Comment: Which readings?

Comment: power readings?

Comment: I want to increase the range of my setup for which I am adding power amplifier. Is there any way to find what happens before and after adding power amplifier ?

Answer (score 1):

Gain isn't measured in *dBm*, but in *dB*. You need to use a calibrated measurement room, antenna, and RF power meter to measure the power leaving your antenna.

You can skip the measurement room and antenna part if you just directly connect your USRP to your RF power meter and measure power.

Answer (score 0):

To find the power out of the radio, find the power in, then add 17 to 20 dB.

To find the power into the radio, you have to know the local signal strength of what you are trying to receive, and the gain of the antenna.  You say the latter is 3 dBi, which means it picks up 3 dB more in the horizontal direction relative to what a isotropic receiver would pick up.  The "i" in dBi stands for "isotropic".